# Shared hosting - website - how to get app to find dlls

Tags: asp.net, dll

I have an ASP.Net application running on a shared hosting website. The app uses 2 dlls I created. But if I put the dlls in the website root bin folder the site won't load. If I put them anywhere else the app can't find the dlls. The app runs locally on my pc fine with the dlls in the bin folder. I added the references for the dlls to my project with the option to copy locally set to true. I contacted support for the website and they said put the dlls in a new bin folder outside of the root directory (wwwroot), which I did. The instructions also said to edit the web.config file with certain additions, which I tried, but I got errors about the wrong module type found in the new web.config file.

If I reomove the dlls from the wwwroot/bin folder, the following is the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Unable to load DLL 'trim_combos.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'trim_combos.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'trim_combos.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]
   Powerball.trim(Int32[,] array, Int32 total, Int32 match) +0
   Powerball.combos_2() +26
   Lottery_C_Sharp_ASP._Default.Button15_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +86
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

If I put the dlls in the wwwroot/bin folder I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'find_duplicates.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'find_duplicates.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'find_duplicates.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'find_duplicates.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +736
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +284
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'find_duplicates.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930568
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Below is the sample their support gave me on how to edit the web.config. I think if I could get some help on how to do this correctly without errors that would fix the problem. Namely the module-type to use:

```
<configuration>

<configSections>
<section name=”MODULE”
type=”MODULE_TYPE, DLL_NAME” />
</configSections>

<system.web>
<httpModules>
<add name=”MODULE” type=”MODULE_TYPE, DLL_NAME” />
</httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=”true”>
<add name=”MODULE” type=”MODULE_TYPE” />
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration=”false” />
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Your DLL's should be in the bin folder. That's where they belong. If your site won't load, then you have another problem, and it's impossible for us to know what that is without you posting the specific error information. We aren't magical beings-don't expect us to know what your errors are without you telling us.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Without having any of the specifics, it sounds to me like an IIS configuration issue and whether your Asp.net app should be it's own website (outside of wwwroot) or configured as an IIS application under the default IIS website. Detailed error messages would get you better answers.

Comment: I edited the original post with the error messages. There are 2 dlls, find_duplicates.dll and trim_combos.dll. The first error occurs when I click on of the buttons on the main page, the second just loading the page.